# Best practice for building shared-object (.so) in C that will be used from different FFI including JAVA (JNI) and NodeJs (node-ffi)

Tags: c, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I know the basics on how to make C library java compatible using JNI, but I need this same library to be used by the other tech as well. 
I checked around and all solutions are built for either FFI or JNI... 
Any experience for global solution using same code, maybe different make-file, or... 
thanks

```
// Save as "HelloJNI.c"
#include <jni.h>        // JNI header provided by JDK
#include <stdio.h>      // C Standard IO Header
#include "HelloJNI.h"   // Generated

// Implementation of the native method sayHello()
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return;
}
```

so what I need somebody doing this kind of work for years to give me some best practices :-).

Comment: I would have developed common code + multiple adapters - each for the technology you want to connect with. With NodeJS you will need module, for Java, a JNI based wrapper code.

Comment: I agree, there is not going to be a single binary shared library that can be loaded by both platforms as they have different binary interfaces for loading native code.  As pointed out above, create a stand alone native library and two wrapper libraries to connect to FFI and JNI respectively.  These wrappers are going to handle all of your native to run-time type conversions, exposing methods, error handling, etc.  You can connect the native library to its respective wrapper using static linking and LTO to get a pretty good end result.  Example project: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook